# C programming type casting and fixed point

Tags: c

How should you implement this function in C code?

```
U16 newValue function(U16 value, S16 x, U16 y){
   newValue = min((((value - x) * y) >> 10) >> 4, 4095)
   return newValue
}
```

y is fixed point with 10 fractional bits

If x is greater then value the final result should be 0.

My concern is the mix between different types especially and that overflow does not occur. Also how to write it in a clean why if there will be a lot of type casts.

Comment: Which function do you refer to from your code snippet, the `min` function?

Comment: Please provide clear and correct code (maybe pseudo code) to begin with. Here we are missing all the context. Is it supposed to be C? If yes, what is the question? What are `U16`, `min`?

Comment: @JensGustedt we're all developpers here, I think we can all deduce what `U16` and `min` mean.

Comment: @sturcotte06, sorry I can't, there are too many open issues and I simply don't understand the question. E.g is this misterious type `U16` supposed to be at least as wide as `int`? The whole meaning of the code can change. If I apply some guessing to the types, I come up with a version of it where the `>> 10` is performed on a signed integer. Is that intentional? In short, this question is poor quality.

Comment: `S16` => signed int of 16 bits, `U16` => unsigned int of 16 bits, `min` => function always implemented with the same signature, returns the lowest number of two given numbers. Deduction is an art I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code the fucntion for all possible values of the parameters given in input. Take the expression `(value - x)`. If `value` is equal to 2^16 and `x` is equal to 2^(-15), then the result of `(value - x)` would be 98304, bigger than a `U16`. Therefore, I would cast `value` to `S32` before this operation.

Let's collapse the expression `(value - x)` to its maximum value 98304. The maximum value of the expression `((value - x) * y)` would then be 98304 * 2^16 which is equal to 6442450944, which is a bigger value than a 32 bits integer can hold. Therefore, you'd need to compute this expression as an `U64`. You can simply replace the initial `U32` cast to a `S64` cast, since you'll need it anyway.

Right bit shift operations only reduce the number of significant bits. Therefore, this does not require a bigger number of bits to be computed.

The `min` call ensures that the result cannot be bigger than 4095, which can be held in a `U16`; no more cast should be necessary.

Final function:

```
uint16_t newValue(uint16_t value, int16_t x, uint16_t y){
    int64_t newValue = (int64_t)(value);
    newValue -= x;
    newValue *= y;
    newValue >>= 10;
    newValue >>= 4;
    newValue = min(newValue, 4095);

    // Or as a one liner.
    // uint64_t newValue = min(((((int64_t)value - x) * y) >> 10) >> 4, 4095);

    return (uint16_t) newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but what happens after multiplication with y that is fixed point? The ">> 10" shift is to truncate the fractional part after the fixed point multiplication.

Comment: Everything is fixed point, there's no float in there, is there?

Comment: The y input is in fixed point with 10 fractional bits and I have to right shift the result with 10 after multiplication with y to truncate the fractional part. I think this is no problem with an unsigned int but not sure what happens when you do this with a signed int.

Comment: Well, all your parameters are fixed point (signed int 16 and unsigned int 16). Passing a float as an int is a code smell, and you should scold your teacher if he teaches you that. From the pseudo-code you gave, all parameters are integers and an integer is returned. If this somehow does magic in floating point land, you're only looking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
unsigned int function(unsigned int value, signed int x, unsigned int y){
  if((((value - x) * y) >> 10) >> 4<4095)
  return (((value - x) * y) >> 10) >> 4;
  else return 4095;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution,explain it.

Comment: Tell me which line is bothering u?